# How to listen to any Entry change events?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm writing a little program that populates values that come from an API every second into Entry components. But also I need for the user to be able to change any of the values anytime by themselves.
So what I have right now is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
sv = StringVar()

def callback():
    print(sv.get())
    return True

e = Entry(root, textvariable=sv, validate="key", validatecommand=callback)
e.grid()
e = Entry(root)
e.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

This way I can activate my callback function whenever they press a key. However, I need it to happen also when the value is changed by the API ticker that changes the Entry components. I need my function to be called whenever any Entry text/value is changed on any Entry.
I used to code in Delphi and there we had an onChage event for edits, but in Python I'm a little lost.

Comment: You can `trace` changes on your `StringVar` which is set as a textvariable for your entry.

Comment: That's a start. I'll do some research, thanks

Comment: trace is passing to my function 3 parameters, what happens if I need to pass my own parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `trace` method on your `StringVar`:

```
def trace_method(*args):
    #do your thing...

sv.trace("w",trace_method)
```

If you need to pass a parameter, you can use `lambda`:

```
def trace_method(*args,parameter=None):
    if parameter:
        print (parameter)

sv.trace("w",lambda *args: trace_method(parameter="Something"))
```